# A functional subcomponent doesn't rerender on props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a very heavy (computationally) functional component (Parent) which doesn't have a state and has few Child sub-components with local state. Children are dependent only on props send from the Parent.

I pass a function to one of the children (ChildA) to change the value of a variable on the Parent.

This variable is one of the props of a different Child component (ChildB) which has a state based on that prop and updates it in useEffect hook.

The ChildB component does not re-render when the value passed as prop changes on the Parent component.

Sure, introducing state (useState hook) on Parent fixes this but re-renders the parent over and over and kills the performance as Parent has 500+ nested components which all get re-rendered.

Introducing some kind of a Store (Redux, MobX) would probably solve the issue but that would be an overkill.

A simplified example:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  return <Parent />    
}

const ChildA = ({ onAction }) => {
  return <button onClick={onAction}>CLICK</button>;
};

const ChildB = ({ coreValue }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(coreValue);
  }, [coreValue]);

  return <div>My value: {value}</div>;
};

const Parent = () => {
  let calculatedValue = 0;

  const changeValue = () => {
    calculatedValue += Math.random();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ChildA onAction={changeValue} />
      <ChildB coreValue={calculatedValue} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

You can test the code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-wave-r27rg

How do I re-render only ChildB on props change?

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the value in parent component state and just send the parent component state value to the ChildB, there you don't need to maintain state and useEffect hook to catch the change. See the code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-chatelet-sjjfs

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  return <Parent />;
}
const ChildA = ({ onAction }) => {
  return <button onClick={onAction}>CLICK</button>;
};
const ChildB = ({ coreValue }) => {
  return <div>My value: {coreValue}</div>;
};
const Parent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const changeValue = () => {
    setValue(value + Math.random());
  };
  return (
    <div>
       <ChildA onAction={changeValue} />
       <ChildB coreValue={value} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Yes and no - this will solve the problem of not re-rendering the ChildB but it will cause the Parent re-render and I have to avoid this as this will cause a cascade of re-renders for more than 500 components. I need to re-render ChildB only.

Comment: Agree!!! But this is the only way you can do with component state. If you are using application store (Redux store), then you can directly update and use the value from there.

Answer (score 0):

React's `useCallback` and `memo` prevent's unnecessary re-rendering. Note that ChildA doesn't re-render regardless of the number of times the `Parent` or `ChildB` state's changes. Also, your current example doesn't need `useState` / `useEffect` in `ChildB`

https://codesandbox.io/s/usecallback-and-memo-ptkuj

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, memo, useCallback } from "react";

export default function App() {
  return <Parent />;
}

const ChildA = memo(({ onAction }) => {
  console.log("ChildA rendering");
  return <button onClick={onAction}>CLICK</button>;
});

const ChildB = memo(({ coreValue }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(coreValue);
  }, [coreValue]);

  return <div>My value: {value}</div>;
});

const Parent = () => {
  const [calculatedValue, setCalculatedValue] = useState(0);

  const changeValue = useCallback(() => {
    setCalculatedValue(c => (c += Math.random()));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <ChildA onAction={changeValue} />
      <ChildB coreValue={calculatedValue} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hmm, this might work but memoizing someone subcomponents will be tricky. I guess I will add a store to the project to avoid all this hassle. Thanks for your suggestion.